# Анимация гамбургер меню

Tags: html, css, css3, анимация, svg

Я работаю над  анимацией меню  гамбургера, где меню  при щелчке превращается в две формы: треугольник  и шеврон справа от него.

У меня  есть некоторые проблемы со сглаживанием анимации. Использую `border-color`, чтобы выполнить то, что хочу, но   при двойном щелчке (= «обратная» анимация) реализуется не так гладко, как стартовая анимация.

HTML и CSS:

```css
body {
  background-color: #252626;
}
div {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 100px;
  div {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 30px 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  }
}
.one, .three {
  background-color: #DFBA68;
  height: 12px;
}

.one-clicked, .three-clicked {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.one-clicked {
  transform: rotate(33deg) scale(.93, 1);
  top: 90px;
}

.two {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid #F7F4EA;
    border-left: 200px solid #F7F4EA;
    border-bottom: 25px solid #F7F4EA;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out, border-color .1ms ease-in-out .2s;
}

.two-clicked{
  width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-left: 150px solid #F7F4EA;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out, border-color .1ms ease-in-out;
}

.three-clicked{
  transform: rotate(-33deg) scale(.93, 1);
  top: -87px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Может ли кто-нибудь  помочь мне, сгладить эту полную анимацию для меня?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Hamburger menu animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33779056/7394871) от участника  [@Pieter VDE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2286419/pieter-vde).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779056/hamburger-menu-animation/33783283#33783283

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я немного позанимался  анимацией иконки меню гамбургера. Полностью переработал код с помощью `svg`, и использовал библиотеку [snapsvg.io](http://snapsvg.io/) для анимации.

Ниже `gif` результата:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**codepen demo для**  [animated burger icon](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/QjodMB)

Обратите внимание, что функция - `bounce easing function` может быть изменена для облегчения или изменения параметров анимации.

Здесь полный код:

```js
var s           = Snap().attr({viewBox:'0 0 100 100'}),
    mid         = s.path("M0 40L100 40L100 60L0 60").attr({fill:"#F7F4EA"}),
    ext         = s.path('M0 20L100 20M100 80L0 80').attr({strokeWidth: 4,stroke:"#DFBA68"}),
    clicked     = 0;

s.click(function(){
  if (clicked == 0){
    mid.animate({d:"M0 5L55 50L55 50L0 95"},700,mina.bounce);
    ext.animate({d:"M40 5L90 51.15M90 48.85L40 95"},700,mina.bounce);
    clicked=1;
  }  
  else {
    mid.animate({d:"M0 40L100 40L100 60L0 60"},700,mina.bounce);
    ext.animate({d:"M0 20L100 20M100 80L0 80"},700,mina.bounce);
    clicked=0;
  }
});
```

```css
html{height:100%;}
body{min-height:100%; background-color:#252626;text-align:center;}
svg{width:20%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg.js"></script>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33783283/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>